# MySQL query - count how many user is registred on event (men&women)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm a beginner in MySQL and I need to write query to select all rows from event table and count how many users are registered on this event (but I need to split users by gender).

My tables:

**table event:**

```
id
event_name
...and another insignificant column
```

**table user:**

```
id
username
gender (allowed values: male or female)
...and another insignificant column
```

**table user_on_event:**

```
event_id (link to event table to column ID)
user_id (link to user table to column ID)
```

and this query:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(user_on_event.user_id) as total_registred_users_on_event FROM event LEFT JOIN user_on_event ON user_on_event.event_id = event.id
```

This selects everything from event table and counts all registered users. This is OK, but I need to also count registered women and men.

What do I have modify in my query to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 
    sum(gender = 'male') male_count,
    sum(gender = 'female') female_count,
    count(*) total_count
from user_on_event uoe
join user u on u.id = uoe.user_id
```

if you want counts for a specific event add

```
where uoe.event_id = :event_id
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe I have got it :) is this query looks OK? what do you think?

```
SELECT *, COUNT(user_on_event.user_id) as total_registred_users_on_event,
(SELECT COUNT(user.id) FROM user WHERE user.id = user_on_event.user_id 
AND user.gender = "male") as men, 
(SELECT COUNT(user.id) FROM user 
WHERE user.id = user_on_event.user_id 
AND user.gender = "female") as women FROM event 
LEFT JOIN user_on_event ON user_on_event.event_id = event.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT event.id, event_name, gender, COUNT(*) from event 
INNER JOIN user_on_event ON event_id = event.id
INNER JOIN user ON user.id = user_id
GROUP BY event.id, event_name, gender
```

this query only scan the table once instead of 3 times if you do Select count twice + select *. But you will see 1-2 rows for each event, one for man one for women.